# Example of ASIHTTPRequest with TouchXML 

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, touchxml

I am currently using NSXMLParser mathods to parse my data something like this :




But I found some good option as TouchXML .

I  googled  for some good example or tutorial

But I can't understand the XPathquery format and the parsing loops as done in this [example](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/)

or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373609/simplexml-way-of-parsing-in-objective-c-for-iphone-app/1375352#1375352)

I just want to know how to parse a simple xml document like this :

```
<ElementsArray>
  <ElementObject>
    <element1></element1>
    <element2></element1>
  <ElementObject>
. 
.
.
<ElementArray>
```

so can anyone give me example code or a link will also be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coolest part of using TouchXML is that you can use the Apple documentation for NSXML and simply replace the NS with C. So an NSXMLDocument is a CXMLDocument and an NSXMLNode is a CXMLNode, and so on. Just look at the [Tree-Based XML Programming Guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html) for sample code and you should get a pretty good idea of how to use TouchXML with your XML documents. The section [Querying an XML Document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html) should give you what you need to use XPath effectively.